# Gulp browser-sync ENOENT error

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

Running gulp serve, results in the following error:

```
[BS] [debug] Getting option: socket.path
[BS] [debug] Getting option: socket.namespace

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
```

It only appears, when running browser-sync, here's my browser-sync config:

```
browserSync({
    notify: false,
    server: {
        baseDir: ['app']
    },
    watchOptions: {
        debounceDelay: 250
    },
    startPath: "/" + view + ".html",
    injectChanges: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    browser: ["google chrome"] 
});
```

I'm running the following versions:

node: 0.10.33
gulp: 3.8.10
browser-sync: 1.8.2 (also tried 1.9.x)

The startpath is correct and exists, disabling ghostMode doesnt help.

Comment: Problem was the following line:

browser: ["google chrome"] 

I thought I tried that already, but apperantly not. If anyone knows why that doesn't work, this would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this: browser: 'google-chrome'

Answer (score 0):

I found [this comment](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/777#issuecomment-132558575) to provide the best option:

```
browser: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'MAC_OS_X_SPECIFIC_BROWSER' : 'OTHER'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with ?

```
browserSync({browser: ['chrome']});
```

Answer (score -2):

browser: 'google-chrome' -  is the correct config.
When you configuring your BrowerSync use 'google-chrome' with dash instead of 'google chrome' or 'chrome'. So your config should look like:

```
browserSync({ 
  notify: false, 
  server: { baseDir: ['app'] }, 
  watchOptions: { debounceDelay: 250 }, 
  startPath: "/" + view + ".html", 
  injectChanges: true, 
  logLevel: "debug", 
  browser: "google-chrome" 
});
```

Comment: You mean, leave out square brackets and add hyphen? Like in the [answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32566217/2083613)?

Comment: When you configuring your BrowerSync use 'google-chrome' with dash instead of 'google chrome' or 'chrome'.
So your config should look like: 

```browserSync({
    notify: false,
    server: {
        baseDir: ['app']
    },
    watchOptions: {
        debounceDelay: 250
    },
    startPath: "/" + view + ".html",
    injectChanges: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    browser: "google-chrome"
});```

Sorry if my comment was not full enough.